The new ask page "Step 1: Draft your question" has a few problems: what should we change it to?
When asking questions, we now have this message:


The community is here to help you with questions about Chinese language. Provide details and share research with your question.

See The new ask page is now live on the network! on meta.SE.
There's some problems:

First it's ungrammatical: it should say "the Chinese language" or "Chinese languages".  (As a workaround, it's possible to use "Chinese language" as a compound adjective; see below.)
I feel "share research" is not clear: whose research should I share?  Is Googling something considered "research"?
I'm not keen on "here to help you"---we're not here for any specific individual.  (We used to say things like "repository of knowledge".)
I also strongly encourage including a link to the on-topic page---it's very hard to find with the modern design (unless you already know it exists, and where to look).

The meta.SE post says this is customizable.  So...
Question: What should we change it to?
Here's a first draft:

You are participating in a Chinese-language Q&A community.  We strive for on-topic questions which are detailed and answerable so as to benefit future readers.  Please pinpoint a problem and describe prior research, i.e., what you have already discovered.

I went with something succinct, but it's possible to make it longer.  So, it may also be worthwhile adding e.g.:

There's also a list of resources and a "what does this say?" guide.


Here's the example from CodeReview.SE:

As you see, it's much longer, so that's a possibility.

A short one sentence stigmatization can be added at the first. Like "Learn the Chinese language" or "You can know more about the Chinese language here with the help of the community".
And to my, a "Chinese-language Q&A community" is a little ambiguous, as it may be a community where Chinese is used, but anything can be discussed.

I agree, this draft still need ssome further editing to clarify the sentiment, the original can be improved but we should hmaer it out clearly if we are changing it.  Perhaps saying "solution orientated chinese-language exchange" or something along those lines.  Even my version also needs tweaking.
